# Get node text only if contain an attribute?

Tags: xpath

XPath problem.

I have these nodes:

```
[...]
<videos>
  <video timestamp="201204271112">myVideo.avi</video>
  <video>myVideo.avi</video>
  <video timestamp="201204271113">myVideo.avi</video>
  <video>myVideo.avi</video>
  <video>myVideo.avi</video>
</videos>
<photos>
  <photo timestamp="201204271112">myphoto.avi</video>
  <photo>myphoto.avi</video>
  <photo timestamp="201204271113">aphoto.avi</video>
  <photo>myphoto.avi</video>
  <photo>myphoto.avi</video>
</photos>    
[...]
```

How can i get only node `text` that contains `timestamp` attribute?

I tried

```
//@timestamp
```

it returns ALL timestamps attribute only. And the text?

How can make a query that include all two conditions? `AND` condition.

Something like this:

```
//@text and //@timestamps
```

to get only
201204271112 - myVideo.avi
201204271113 - myVideo.avi
201204271113 - aphoto.avi
excluding other ones?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can i get only node `text` that contains `timestamp` attribute?

Could you mean `//*[@timestamp]/text()`? That selects all text nodes whose parents have the `timestamp` attribute.

The conditions are in XPaths, too (i.e. `//video[@timestamp and text()]` selects all `video` nodes that have both `timestamp` and some text nodes).

What you probably meant is a node-set union used with symbol `|`. To get both the timestamps and the text nodes, you'll need two queries unioned together: `//@timestamp | //*[@timestamp]/text()` gets all timestamps and all their text nodes. However, I don't think you can get it nicely aligned (there will be all timestamps first, then all text nodes).

You can try either iterating one by one with some kind of `for` loop and get both the timestamp and the text node via `position`, or you can just get all nodes that have a timestamp and dig their text out of them later (which is a preffered way).

[The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) is a surprisingly good read on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can match on attributes:

```
//video[@timestamp]/text()
```

//video = matches a node with name video anywhere in the treee

[@timestamp] is a predicate, meaning the node has to have this attribute

text() selects all text node children of the current node